# What is the correct tick size for the Nikkei 225 mini futures?

Tags: futures

I would like to know the tick size equivalent for the Nikkei 225 m futures contracts.

I can find different information:

https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/NPH20/profile with:

**Tick Size:    10 points (JPY 2,000 per contract)**

but in contrast:

https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/derivatives/products/domestic/225mini/01.html

**Tick Size:    ¥5 (Value per tick: ¥500 per contract)**

Which information is correct?

Comment: Who would you rather trust? The exchange or an outdated commercial website?

Comment: You are right indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPX information is correct.

Comment: I asked the barchart support about their opinion. First they recited the information that is available at their link stated above. After I pointed out the differences between their site and www.jpx.co.jp, I did not got an answer until now. So you are very probably right :-)

Answer (score 1):

The exchange is always the authoratitive source wrt contract specifications.